# Testing .NET code in partial trust environments

Tags: .net, code-access-security

I want to test the behavior of a certain piece of .NET code in partial trust environments.  What's the fastest way to set this up?  Feel free to assume that I (and other readers) are total CAS noobs.

@Nick: Thanks for the reply.  Alas, the tool in question is explicitly for unmanaged code.  I didn't say "managed" in my question, and should not have assumed that people would infer it from the ".NET" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent question, especially from a TDD point of view and validating code under different trust scenarios.

I think the way I'd approach this would be something along the lines of -

- Create an AppDomain in my TDD code using the AppDomain.CreateDomain() overload that allows you to pass in a PermissionSet. The PermissionSet would be constructed to match the different trust scenarios you'd want to test against.
- Load the assembly containing logic under test into the app domain
- Create instances of types/call methods etc in app domain, trap security exceptions

Something kinda like that. I've not had time to knock up a proof of concept yet.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you're looking for is built-in into visual studio :

On the security tab of your project, there's an "Advanced ..." button which let you configure whether you want to debug in full trust, or on a specified trust level.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bd02c19c-1250-433c-8c1b-2619bd93b3a2&displaylang=en).

AppVerifier helps to determine:

- When the application is using APIs correctly:
        (Unsafe TerminateThread APIs., Correct use of Thread Local Storage (TLS) APIs.,          o Correct use of virtual space manipulations (for example, VirtualAlloc, MapViewOfFile).
- Whether the application is hiding access violations using structured exception handling.
- Whether the application is attempting to use invalid handles.
- Whether there are memory corruptions or issues in the heap.
- Whether the application runs out of memory under low resources.
- Whether the correct usage of critical sections is occurring.
- Whether an application running in an administrative environment will run well in an environment with less privilege.
- Whether there are potential problems when the application is running as a limited user.
- Whether there are uninitialized variables in future function calls in a thread's context.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the .NET Framework Configuration Tool.  It's in the .NET SDK, and you can find instructions on running it here...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx

In the *Runtime Security Policy* section you'll find 3 policy levels: Enterprise, Machine and User.  If you drill into Machine or User you'll find definitions of *Code Groups* and *Permission Sets* .  When you say that you want to test some .NET code in partial trust environments, I guess you'll want to test against one of the standard permission sets already defined, such as *Internet* .  You need to define a *Code Group* that matches your app (or specific assemblies) and assign your chosen permission set to that *Code Group* .

You can define your own custom *Permission Sets* too, but let's keep it simple for now.

Choose whether you want your new code group to exist at machine-wide scope, or just for your user account, and drill into the Machine or User policy level accordingly.  You'll see a code group called _All _ Code_ .  Create a child code group inside that one, by right-clicking and selecting *New...*

Give it a name, say *PartialTrustGroup* , then click *Next* .

You have to specify a membership condition for this group, and there are various types.  I like to create a specific folder called *PartialTrust* on my machine, and then create a URL membership condition that matches.  So, my URL looks like this...
file://c:/users/martin/documents/partialtrust/*

The * is a wildcard to catch any assembly beneath that path.  Click *Next* .

Now you can pick a permission set for your new code group.  For now, pick *Internet* .  It's quite a restrictive set, similar to a Java applet sandbox.  Click *Next* and *Finish* .

Now right-click on your new code-group and select Properties.  In the General tab, ensure the topmost checkbox is selected, then click OK.

Now, any .NET assemblies that are loaded from a location beneath the URL you specified will have the *Internet* permission set applied to them.  Expect to get some SecurityExceptions if you haven't written your code to carefully observe the reduced permission set.

Sorry this is a long description.  It really is a lot more simple than it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted an article titled [Partial Trust Testing with xUnit.net](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/08/partial-trust-testing-with-xunitnet.html) on my blog. It details the xUnit.net-based framework that we use on the Entity Framework team to exercise code under medium trust.

Here is an example of its usage.

```
public class SomeTests : MarshalByRefObject
{
    [PartialTrustFact]
    public void Partial_trust_test1()
    {
        // Runs in medium trust
    }
}

// Or...

[PartialTrustFixture]
public class MoreTests : MarshalByRefObject
{
    [Fact]
    public void Another_partial_trust_test()
    {
        // Runs in medium trust
    }
}
```